# Siri is not recognising Vocabulary Item Examples, Vocabulary Item Pronunciation from AppIntentVocabulary.plist

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I made an Xcode project (iOS App) for using Sirikit inside it.
For this purpose I created new target of Intents Extension in my project.
The info.plist file present in SiriKitExtension target has valid IntentsSupported as "InSendMessageIntent" defined as below is the screenshot attached as( [info.plist file which is present in my SiriKitextension Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBPIJ.png))

- I had included AppIntentVocabulary.plist at project level and put it in Base.lproj folder.  The screenshot of content of following file is attached in link. 
  [AppIntentVocabulary.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jMPe.png)
- The AppIntentVocabulary.plist file contains my required voice commands, Vocabulary Item Phrase, Vocabulary Item Pronunciation etc that Siri should recognize while giving commands like "Hey siri, my status using siridemo". Here siridemo is my app's display name.

When I saw a list of example phrases for my SiriDemo app using Siri on iPhone device then I got that Intent examples present in AppIntentVocabulary.plist file is shown there properly and screenshot is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzVWJ.jpg)

Now the exact problem which I am facing is

1. When I say "Send message using SiriDemo" then Siri opens message box properly which has been handled in my IntentHandler.
2. When I say "my status using SiriDemo" then some time Siri does not do any thing and and some time tells to search app on App Store.
3. Some time Siri opens SiriDemo app directly after recognising my app name in the voice command.

So my Question is "With the help of custom voice commands defined in AppIntentVocabulary.plist file, how to open my InSendMessageIntent using Siri ?? " (I don't want to say "Send message using SiriDemo" to open InSendMessageIntent).

Thanks